# Can Apache Spark merge several similar lines into one line?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am totaly new with Apache Spark, therefore, I am very sorry if my question seems to be naive but I did not find a clear answer on internet.

Here is the context of my problem: I want to retrieve json input data from an Apache Kafka server. The format is as follows:

```
{"deviceName":"device1", "counter":125}
{"deviceName":"device1", "counter":125}
{"deviceName":"device2", "counter":88}
{"deviceName":"device1", "counter":125}
{"deviceName":"device2", "counter":88}
{"deviceName":"device1", "counter":125}
{"deviceName":"device3", "counter":999}
{"deviceName":"device3", "counter":999}
```

With Spark or Spark Streaming, i want to process this data and to get as an output the following format:

```
{"deviceName":"device1", "counter":125, "nbOfTimes":4}
{"deviceName":"device2", "counter":88, "nbOfTimes":2}
{"deviceName":"device3", "counter":999, "nbOfTimes":2}
```

So, I would like to know if what I am searching to do is possible with Spark. And if yes, can you give me some guidance about it ? I would be so thankful.

Joe

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with Spark and Spark Streaming. But let's consider the first case with a json file containing your data.

```
val df = sqlContext.read.format("json").load("text.json")
// df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [counter: bigint, deviceName: string]      

df.show
// +-------+----------+
// |counter|deviceName|
// +-------+----------+
// |    125|   device1|
// |    125|   device1|
// |     88|   device2|
// |    125|   device1|
// |     88|   device2|
// |    125|   device1|
// |    999|   device3|
// |    999|   device3|
// +-------+----------+

df.groupBy("deviceName","counter").count.toDF("deviceName","counter","nbOfTimes").show
// +----------+-------+---------+                                                  
// |deviceName|counter|nbOfTimes|
// +----------+-------+---------+
// |   device1|    125|        4|
// |   device2|     88|        2|
// |   device3|    999|        2|
// +----------+-------+---------+
```

Obviously you can write it to any format you want later on. But I think that you get the main idea.

Comment: do you have any idea about ho it can be done with spark streaming ?

Comment: any idea about it, and in java ?

Comment: spark-streaming will follow the same idea. But you are just operating on micro-batched RDDs. I don't see how can that be useful.