# How to parse json data from kafka server with spark streaming?

Tags: json, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I managed to connect spark streaming to my kafka server in which I have data with json format. I want to parse these data in order to do use the function groupby as explained here: [Can Apache Spark merge several similar lines into one line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723796/can-apache-spark-merge-several-similar-lines-into-one-line/38724060#38724060)

In fact, in this link we import json data from a file which is clearly easier to treat. I didn't find someting similar with a kafka server.

Do you have any idea bout it.

Thanks and regards

Comment: PS: Obviously, i wouldn't have asked this question if I didn't find anything in internet

Answer (score 1):

It's really hard to understand what you're asking because we can't see where you are now without code. Maybe this general guidance is what you need.

Your StreamingContext can be given a `foreachRDD` block where you'll get an RDD. Then you can `sqlContext.read.json(inputRDD)` and you will have a DataFrame which you can process however you like.

Comment: I am trying to solve the problem asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38723796/can-apache-spark-merge-several-similar-lines-into-one-line/38724060 . From a specific field in each json data I want to regroup several json data with the same field value..